# How to prevent a React onClick event from being consumed by child

Tags: highcharts, reactjs

I have a React component with an onClick handler.

The component is made of several subcomponents, including one that renders a Highcharts chart.

If I click anywhere on my component OTHER than on the Hichcharts view, the onClick is triggered as expected. If I click on the chart, the onClick is not triggered.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Highcharts is likely consuming the click event. The component rendering the Highchart could pass a reference to its onclick handler to [`chart.events.click`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.click) when it renders the chart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cleanest solution for me was to render a transparent div overtop of the highchart using absolute positioning.

The transparent div gets the events first and is handled purely by React. This solves all problems.